# Why there is different outputs in running JavaScript on web and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have updated my `Node.Js` into `version 7.6.0` and running google chrome `version 57.0` on the other hand.

When I run this snippet of javascript code, I get two different result like below:

```js
    'use strict'
    
    var obj = {
        id: "awesome",
        cool: function coolFn() {
            console.log(this.id);
        }
    };
    var id = "not awesome";
    obj.cool(); //awsome
    
    setTimeout(obj.cool, 100);
```

result on chrome:

```
awesome
not awesome
```

result on node.js:

```
awesome
undefined
```

Recording to https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/ I even used the `--harmony` flag but the result of node.js didn't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When node runs your file, it's treated as a module, and [the docs say](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) it's effectively wrapped thusly:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  // Your module code actually lives in here
});
```

This means that `var id = "not awesome";` is scoped within that module wrapper, and isn't created as a property on the global object.

When timers fire, `this` is set to the global object.  So in the browser, where `var id` is on the global scope, you see it, whereas in node, it's `undefined`.

If we wrap the code in a function in the browser, you see the same result:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict'
    
    var obj = {
        id: "awesome",
        cool: function coolFn() {
            console.log(this.id);
        }
    };
    var id = "not awesome";
    obj.cool(); //awsome
    
    setTimeout(obj.cool, 100);
})();
```

Comment: thanks for your complete answer, I was wondering if I could get the same result as the browser on node.js according to : https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/apC.md how can I access module scope like the global scope?

Comment: @Ali It really depends on exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.  Judicious use of `.bind` should do the job, but you might be better off with a follow up question.